# Where and when do I make README.md files?

Tags: git, github

I am about to start a project that I will be storing on my computer and making commits via git. I hope to eventually upload this project to github.

Do I put the README.md file inside my folder? Or do I make that at the end when I upload it to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't started your project yet, I'd recommend creating the repository on github first, which will create the README automatically. You can then clone this repo by clicking on the code download button, copying the url it lists (which starts with https://github.com/...) and then running in a terminal in the desired local folder `$ git clone <url>`.